# How to echo items with wildcard '*' in a cmd loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make .gitignore file with codes below:

```
for %i in (*.pyc __pycache__ staticfiles) do (
    echo %i>>.gitignore
)
```

But the loop always skips the *.pyc part, only __pycache__ and staticfiles are printed into the file.
I have searched online for a while, but it seems that nobody else has the same problem as I have here.
I tried to put \,&,|,% before *, but none of these gives the expected output.
Is there any method to print *.pyc out?

Comment: Do you want to write the literal string `*.pyc` to the file? You cannot do that with a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) like this, because `*` and also `?` are [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) that are attempted to be resolved, so the loop returns matching files, and these wildcards cannot be escaped…

Comment: [FOR loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html): _Conditionally perform a command on several files_  **in the current directory**.

Comment: So, there's no way to echo or escape wildcard in loop?

Comment: You could use `(echo *.pyc& echo __pycache__& echo staticfiles)>.gitignore` to create a file with name `.gitignore` with first line `*.pyc`, second line `__pycache__` and third line `staticfiles`. Use `>>` instead of just `>` to append the three lines to an already existing `.gitignore` which is created on not already existing.

Comment: Thanx! This solved the problem. I'd do some improvement to apply this solution to  bigger situations if possible.

Comment: Another solution would be `for %i in (.pyc __pycache__ staticfiles "one more file.txt") do @if not "%~ni" == "" (echo %~i) else echo *%~i)>.gitignore` which (re)creates the file `.gitignore` with the lines `*.pyc`, `__pycache__` `staticfiles` and `one more file.txt`. Please note that in a batch file each `%` must be duplicated resulting in the command line `@for %%i in (.pyc __pycache__ staticfiles "one more file.txt") do @if not "%%~ni" == "" (echo %%~i) else echo *%%~i)>.gitignore`.

Comment: Great! I am still a newbie to bat and cmd. This solution works exactly as expected. I learnt a lot from your codes.